# Automate Excel tasks using perl

Tags: perl, win32ole

I have to automate an excel file, I have already checked [Win32:OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE), just wanted to check if there are some other ways apart from that to achieve similar functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to parse excel try this module Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX and when you are  trying to write something onto excel try this module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and for reading try this module Spreadsheet::Read

Comment: You could also resort to vb script/vba called through the scripting host (cscript.exe). Create an excel application object and use that as the entry point to the excel object model.

Answer (score 1):

Cpan module `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` is a tool to `read information from an Excel file`. An example is here :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to automate actions, the way win32::OLE does, I don't think Spreadsheet::ParseExcel does that.

Comment: I never used `Win32::OLE`, so don't have idea about this.